# Remove trailing slash with htaccess with existing rules

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I wish to remove a trailing slash when one is given using htaccess. What would be the best way to do it that will work with my existing rules as below:

```
  # make sure www. is always there
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  
  # if requested url does not exist pass it as path info to index.php
  RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

A sample URL would be something like:

```
https://www.example.com/this-test/
```

I of course want the ending slash removed.

I've tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R,L]
```

But that does not work with the existing rules that are there. It ends up redirecting to the index.php pages due to the other rules.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/helponnet.com/2020/02/20/how-to-remove-traling-slashes-from-urls-using-rewriterule-url-rewriting-tips/amp/

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in your question, please do mention which samples url you are hitting in your question.

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: Where in your existing rules did you try to insert your new rule?

Comment: I've tried in any position, can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

# if requested url does not exist pass it as path info to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure to test it after completely clearing browser cache.

Comment: Interesting. It's VERY close, but oddly if the first "folder" has a hyphen in the name, it ends up going to the last rule and passing the path to index.php instead?

Comment: There is no hyphen check in `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$` besides by using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` we are skipping all real folders. Real folders should always have a trailing `/` due to security reasons.

Comment: Well, with this rule "RewriteRule ^support-us/?$ /index.php?module=support_us [N]" and your suggestion it ends up as "/support-us?module=support_us" instead of "/support-us".

Comment: That rule is not part of my answer. Is `/support-us/` a real directory?

Comment: No, it's a rewrite rule to have a friendly URL for the page, as shown by my comment.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include ALL your rewrite rules.

Comment: Check my update. You need to place `Options -MultiViews` at the top and always test after clearing browser cache.